# POVMs for which measurement cannot be written as a probabilistic sum of measurements

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-measurements

Consider POVM given by the operators:

- $π ̂_0=\frac{2}{3} |0⟩⟨0|$
- $π ̂_1=\frac{2}{3} (\frac{-1}{2} |0⟩+\frac{√3}{2}|1⟩)(\frac{-1}{2}⟨0|+\frac{√3}{2}⟨1|)$
- $π ̂_2=\frac{2}{3} (-\frac{1}{2} |0⟩-\frac{√3}{2} |1⟩)(\frac{-1}{2} ⟨0|\frac{√3}{2} ⟨1|)$

These are weighted projectors and so are Hermitian and postive by construction.
That they sum to the identity:  $π ̂_0+π ̂_1+π ̂_2=\frac{2}{3} ((1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4})0⟩⟨0|+(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{4}|1⟩⟨1|)=I ̂$

In my notes it goes on to say that:

> Note that this measurement cannot be written as a probabilistic sum of measurements; there is no subset of elements that sums to a multiple of the identity. Nonetheless, it is a POVM and therefore a physically realisable measurement.

I dont understand what is means by the statement "Note that this measurement cannot be written as a probabilistic sum of measurements"

Comment: An alternative interpretation to the answer is that the POVM operators cannot be further decomposed, i.e. the POVM cannot be obtained from another POVM by "binning" outcomes. An examples where this is possible would be the two-outcome POVM with operators $\hat\pi_0$ and $\hat\pi_1+\hat\pi_2$; it can obviously be obtained by performing the POVM above (i.e., decompositing it into it), and then putting the outcomes 1 and 2 into the same bin.

Comment: Also, it would help if you specify *which* notes etc.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch that wouldn't follow from $\pi_1+\pi_2\propto \mathbb{I}$, though. "The notes" seem to specifically be talking about going in the opposite direction, with POVMs being comprised probabilistically of multiple separate POVMs

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Upon another read, I agree. Note, however, that this is still a special case of what I describe above in my comment (each pair of POVM operators with the same outcome give a new POVM operator with the same outcome, which is obtained by binning their outcomes.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch sure but that still confuses the matter. The only way of binning POVMs to make their outcomes the same is to make them trivial (if both sets of POVMs get binned to be equal and they together sum to the identity then they both must be the identity, with appropriate weight factors). But the purpose of the question is not to bin results (i.e., combine them as if "result 0 and result 1 will be labelled A and result 2 will be labelled B") but to see them as if they came from a probabilistic mixture of measurements that retained each individual result

Comment: @QuantumMechanic Hm, I see. Obscure.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch agreed! Forgot to emphasize your above comments asking which notes this comes from! Regardless, the question is well posed and is a reasonable calculation for a homework problem

Answer (score 2):

A probabilistic sum of measurements would be: with probability $p$, do a POVM with elements $\hat{P}_i$ and, with probability $1-p$, do a *different* POVM with elements $\hat{Q}_j$. Each POVM would individually be normalized, with $\sum_i\hat{P}_i=\mathbb{I}=\sum_j\hat{Q}_j$, but there need not be any relationship between the two POVMs.

To ask whether your *given* POVM can be expressed in this form, we would have to split the operators $\hat{\pi}_i$ into two groups that each on their own would be valid POVMs. You might say that's impossible, because if you take only a subset of the POVM elements then the subset POVM would not be properly normalized, but you can scale them by an arbitrary $p$ and the other subset by $1-p$ so it might be possible to still normalize the subsets.

For the given POVM, the only possible subsets are $\{\hat{P}\}=\{\hat{\pi}_0\}$ and $\{\hat{Q}\}=\{\hat{\pi}_1,\hat{\pi}_2\}$ or permutations of those ($\{\hat{P}\}=\{\hat{\pi}_1\}$ and $\{\hat{Q}\}=\{\hat{\pi}_0,\hat{\pi}_2\}$ or $\{\hat{P}\}=\{\hat{\pi}_2\}$ and $\{\hat{Q}\}=\{\hat{\pi}_0,\hat{\pi}_1\}$; since the labels $P$ and $Q$ are arbitrary this covers all the possibilities). Your notes are saying that it is impossible for these to be valid POVMs, because it is impossible to have
$$\hat{\pi}_i=p\mathbb{I}\quad\mathrm{and}\quad \sum_{j\neq i}\hat{\pi}_j=(1-p)\mathbb{I}.$$

This can be generalized slightly if you allow for different weights; then you might be allowed to split your POVM into two subsets $\{\hat{P}\}=\{p_0\hat{\pi}_0,p_1\hat{\pi}_1,p_2\hat{\pi}_2\}$ and $\{\hat{Q}\}=\{(1-p_0)\hat{\pi}_0,(1-p_1)\hat{\pi}_1,(1-p_2)\hat{\pi}_2\}$ and hope for $\sum_i p_i\hat{\pi}_i=p\mathbb{I}$ for some $p\in(0,1)$ [which would guarantee this to also be the cause for $\sum_i (1-p_i)\hat{\pi}_i$]. Then you would have a probabilistic sum of measurements but the two measurements in the probabilistic sum could have the same measurement outcomes as each other, only with different weights. In the case where $p_0=p_1=p_2=1/2$, this would always work, which would be like saying "with 50% chance I do one measurement and with 50% chance I do the *same* measurement," so I assume the notes want to avoid such cases.

Comment: Where does the condition "probabilistic sum of measurements" come from the definition of a POVM.

In you answer you said "Each POVM would individually be normalized, with $\sum_i\hat{P}_i=\mathbb{I}=\sum_j\hat{Q}_j$". I cannot discern from which defination of a POVM, we have that requirement.

Comment: @PhysicsQuestion the definition of a POVM is a set of operators that sum to the identity. So if you have two POVMs, they both have to sum to the identity.

Comment: @PhysicsQuestion you can write it as two separate equalities, if it makes you more comfortable: $\sum_i P_i=\mathbb{I}$ *and* $\sum_j Q_j=\mathbb{I}$

Comment: sorry i still don't understand the statement "measurement cannot be written as a probabilistic sum of measurements". The set operators given are POVM, thus they should be able to perform a measurment. Where does the requirment of "probabilistic sum of measurements" come form.

Comment: @PhysicsQuestion you're worrying too much! The set of operators is indeed a POVM and are able to perform a measurement! The notes are merely saying that you can't split this measurement into two separate measurements.

Comment: If you take another example, you could have a set of POVM elements $|0\rangle\langle 0|/2$, $|1\rangle\langle 1|/2$, $(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)(\langle 0|+\langle 1|)/4$ and $(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)(\langle 0|-\langle 1|)/4$. Then you could consider this measurement to actually be two separate measurements, one performed 50% of the time with POVM elements $|0\rangle\langle 0|$ and $|1\rangle\langle 1|$ and the other performed the other 50% of the time with POVM elements $(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)(\langle 0|+\langle 1|)/2$ and $(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)(\langle 0|-\langle 1|)/2$